# Call rest from Angular 4 with body parameters

Tags: angular, rest

I have a rest web service that I need consume from Angular 4.
Is a post service, that receive only a body parameter in json format:
{
"userName" : "user1",
"passWord" : "123"
}

and I set Content-Type to application/json too but I dont have success.
Can any help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain specifically what is indicating that you are not having success. What is your error? Any code we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it, using httpcliente and observable modules

Ej:

```
http.post(checkUserUrl, payload, {responseType: 'text'}).pipe(
      catchError(new ErrorHandler().handleError('LoginService', null))
    );
```

where payload is an Object in Typescript.

Thanks